# Difference between Python decorator with and without syntactic sugar?

Tags: python, functional-programming, decorator, python-decorators, memoization

I'm trying to implement a decorator that memoizes an arbitrary function. It appears I've successfully accomplished that with the following code:

```
def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        acc = ""
        for arg in args:
            acc += str(arg)
        if acc in cache:
            return cache[acc]
        else:
            cache[acc] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return cache[acc]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Then `fib(100)` returns `573147844013817084101` fairly quickly. However, if I don't use the syntactic sugar:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
memoized = memoize(fib)
print memoized(100)
```

The function hangs. Debugging it, it looks like the wrapper returned is unable to modify the cache. Can someone explain this behavior? As far as I know there shouldn't be a difference between using the sugar and not using the sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive call is not memoized, because you used a *new name*, not the original `fib` function name. Each `fib()` iteration calls back to `fib()`, but that will call the *original, undecorated function*.

Assign the return value of the decorator call to `fib` instead:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
fib = memoize(fib)
print fib(100)
```

Alternatively, if you must use `memoize` as the name of the decorator result, have `fib()` call `memoized()` for recursive calls:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return memoized(n - 1) + memoizzed(n - 2)
memoized = memoized(fib)
print memoized(100)
```

Remember, the `@decorator` syntax assigns to *the same name*, not a new name. The following two are equivalent:

```
@memoize
def fib(n):
    # ....
```

and

```
def fib(n):
    # ....
fib = memoize(fib)  # Same name!
```

except the name `fib` is never bound to the original function first.